# Select a tag nested within a ":last" selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

What is the selector syntax to select a tag after using the ":last" selector?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Cell 1
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        The tag I want to get
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm using the following, to no avail:

```
$("table td:last table")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$("table table td:last")
```

Comment: That worked.  I also got table td:last:table to work.  Is there a difference?

Comment: im not sure why table td:last:table would work, as there is no :table pseudo selector. If you meant table td:last then it will work because it finds 3 td of which the one you want is last. but it wouldnt work if you hade three td's in your base table.